# ¿Como fijar el tamaño de las celdas (responsivo)?

Tags: html, css

Este es mi código, anteriormente si me respetaba el ancho de mi celda, pero ya insertando los datos mi tabla se vuelve mas pequeña!

```css
.grande {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="tableh">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">No. de Riesgo</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Responsable</td>
 <td rowspan="2" class="grande">Riesgo</td>
 <td rowspan="2">objetivo(PIID)</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Debilidades & Amenazas</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Indicador Plan Rector</td>
 <td colspan="2">Clasificacion del riesgo</td>
 <td colspan="4">Factor</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Posibles efectos del Riesgo</td>
 <td colspan="3">Valoracion Inicial</td>
 <td rowspan="2">¿Tiene Controles?</td>
 <td colspan="3">Control</td>
 <td colspan="5">Determinacion de Sufuciencia o Deficiencia del control</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Riesgo Controlado Suficientemente</td>
 <td colspan="2">Valoracion Final</td>
 <td colspan="4">Ubicacion en cuadrantes</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Estrategia para Administrar el Riesgo</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Descripción de la(s) Acción(es)</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>Seleccion</td>
 <td>Especificar otro</td>
 <td>No. de Factor</td>
 <td>Descripcion</td>
 <td>Clasificacion</td>
 <td>Tipo</td>
 <td>Grado de impacto</td>
 <td>Probabilidad de Ocurrrencia</td>
 <td>Cuadrante</td>
 <td>No.</td>
 <td>Descripcion</td>
 <td>Tipo</td>
 <td>Esta Documentado</td>
 <td>Esta Formalizado</td>
 <td>Se Aplica</td>
 <td>Es efectivo</td>
 <td>Resultado de la determinacion del control</td>
 <td>Grado de impacto</td>
 <td>Probabilidad de Ocurrencia</td>
 <td>I</td>
 <td>II</td>
 <td>III</td>
 <td>IV</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Probá agregando min-width: 300px (sin sacar width: 300)

Comment: gracias Victoria Ruiz! eso resolvió el lo de la celda!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

agrega un min-width en la celda que deceas tener esa anchura algo asi

```css
.grande {
    width: 300px;
    min-width:300px;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" class="tableh">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">No. de Riesgo</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Responsable</td>
 <td rowspan="2" class="grande">Riesgo</td>
 <td rowspan="2">objetivo(PIID)</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Debilidades & Amenazas</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Indicador Plan Rector</td>
 <td colspan="2">Clasificacion del riesgo</td>
 <td colspan="4">Factor</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Posibles efectos del Riesgo</td>
 <td colspan="3">Valoracion Inicial</td>
 <td rowspan="2">¿Tiene Controles?</td>
 <td colspan="3">Control</td>
 <td colspan="5">Determinacion de Sufuciencia o Deficiencia del control</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Riesgo Controlado Suficientemente</td>
 <td colspan="2">Valoracion Final</td>
 <td colspan="4">Ubicacion en cuadrantes</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Estrategia para Administrar el Riesgo</td>
 <td rowspan="2">Descripción de la(s) Acción(es)</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr>
 <td>Seleccion</td>
 <td>Especificar otro</td>
 <td>No. de Factor</td>
 <td>Descripcion</td>
 <td>Clasificacion</td>
 <td>Tipo</td>
 <td>Grado de impacto</td>
 <td>Probabilidad de Ocurrrencia</td>
 <td>Cuadrante</td>
 <td>No.</td>
 <td>Descripcion</td>
 <td>Tipo</td>
 <td>Esta Documentado</td>
 <td>Esta Formalizado</td>
 <td>Se Aplica</td>
 <td>Es efectivo</td>
 <td>Resultado de la determinacion del control</td>
 <td>Grado de impacto</td>
 <td>Probabilidad de Ocurrencia</td>
 <td>I</td>
 <td>II</td>
 <td>III</td>
 <td>IV</td>  
    </tr>
</table>
```